# ( Sum Measure ) when unfiltered sum everything except 2 values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a card and i want it to display a sum of A-1 and A-2 and give me a value of 10 but in the same time if i selected B-2 or B-2 i should see their specific value like (4) in the card.

[image]

I can filter out the values manually in card but then, if i selected the filtered out values, the card will display a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a simple sum.
you can just create a measure sum

```
Sum(Column B)
```

And add a slicer based on you column A.

If you select data in the slicer the sum will be automatically adapted.